# Import not working same

Tags: reactjs, es6-module-loader

Hi on my server is this working:

```
import api_url from '../../../../.react.config';
```

and on another it is not. Instead I have to use:

```
import {api_url} from '../../../../.react.config';
```

both are using node 4.2.2

can anybody explain why?

Comment: It's the exact same path.

Comment: sory I had a typo there, i eddited question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first syntax will use the module's default export.

```
export default { };
// or in commonjs
module.exports = { };
```

If you haven't declared a default export, then importing the entire module won't work.

The second syntax is a destructuring pattern which will only work if the module exports a named property.

```
export const api_url = ' ';
// commonjs
exports.api_url = ' ';
```

v4.2.2 doesn't support ES6 module syntax, so you are probably using a tool to transpile your code.

- Check that the statements in both files are being transpiled to equivalent ES5 code.
- Make sure that the module's exports are the same on both servers.

Comment: Thanks I checked again exports and there was a mistake, I forget that export file is in .gitignore file, so it can be different

one has export const and second has export default